# how to access img element without id in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to access img element in javascript due to my project there is one limitation that i can't make changes in html code here is the code
i have to use event listener to img how it can b done? anyone ?

```
<table id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Profile Pic</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>Gates</td> 
        <td><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Xqko1Y9prZ6JoHkVERPfK6rJJuE=/0x0:640x427/1200x800/filters:focal(269x163:371x265)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56196289/billgatestock.0.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brian</td>
        <td>Bad Luck</td> 
        <td><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-f4r5N2n5nz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LLysC2ZLPUo/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Barista</td>
        <td>Hipster</td> 
        <td><img src="http://diffuser.fm/files/2014/02/Hipster.jpg?w=600&h=0&zc=1&s=0&a=t&q=89" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) should do.

Comment: Can you show your JS code? Are you able to use jQuery?

Comment: Do you want all of them, or are you just after a specific one? Unless you've been told you need a listener for the exercise you're doing, you don't need a listener.

Comment: i want all of them but each has a different effects with event listener @Andy

Comment: my js code is here **    var el = document.getElementById('table')
el.addEventListener("click", changeMe);
 el.addEventListener("mouseover", changeMe );
 el.addEventListener("dblclick", changeMe);

 
    function changeMe () {

      alert ("Hello World!");
     
    }**

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

Should get all img elements for you

After that you can execute a function per image like this

```
const images = [...document.getElementsByTagName("img")];
images.forEach(image => { /* Do something per image */ });
```

Comment: thanks @Jelle it works perfectly but just need to use array with img like    ' document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];'

Comment: Yes, you get an array like structure back. I updated the answer on how to use a forEach over the images

Answer (score 0):

Use query Selector All

```js
var img=document.querySelectorAll('img')
console.log(img[0])
console.log(img[1])
console.log(img[2])
```

```html
<table id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Profile Pic</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>Gates</td> 
        <td><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Xqko1Y9prZ6JoHkVERPfK6rJJuE=/0x0:640x427/1200x800/filters:focal(269x163:371x265)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56196289/billgatestock.0.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brian</td>
        <td>Bad Luck</td> 
        <td><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-f4r5N2n5nz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LLysC2ZLPUo/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Barista</td>
        <td>Hipster</td> 
        <td><img src="http://diffuser.fm/files/2014/02/Hipster.jpg?w=600&h=0&zc=1&s=0&a=t&q=89" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get references to all the images. I'm not sure to which of them you need to attach an event listener, so here is an example that attaches the one to every image:

```js
const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

Array.from(images).forEach((image, index) => {
    image.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log(`Image ${index} was clicked`)
    })
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Profile Pic</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>Gates</td> 
        <td><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Xqko1Y9prZ6JoHkVERPfK6rJJuE=/0x0:640x427/1200x800/filters:focal(269x163:371x265)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56196289/billgatestock.0.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brian</td>
        <td>Bad Luck</td> 
        <td><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-f4r5N2n5nz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LLysC2ZLPUo/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Barista</td>
        <td>Hipster</td> 
        <td><img src="http://diffuser.fm/files/2014/02/Hipster.jpg?w=600&h=0&zc=1&s=0&a=t&q=89" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Collect `<img>` Into a NodeList and Iterate With `for (...of...)`

The following solution resolves situations where there ***are images outside of the `<table>`*** but you only want what's inside the `<table>`.

- Reference the `<tbody>` of `<table>`

> > ```
> >  document.querySelector('tbody')
> > ```

- Collect the images within the `<table>`

> > ```
> >  var images = document.querySelector('tbody').querySelectorAll('img');
> > ```

- `images` is a NodeList of 3 `<img>`. To use an array or array-like object you should iterate through it:

> > ```
> >   for (let img of images) {...
> > ```

- Although the name of the first parameter (`img`) is arbitrary, it needs to be there. In the demo, each image should have a red outline, this of course is just for demonstration. The `for...of` loop is similar to the classic `for(...)` loop but is more versatile and less error prone.

---

### Demo

```js
var images = document.querySelector('tbody').querySelectorAll('img');

for (let img of images) {

  img.style.outline = '2px solid tomato';

}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Profile Pic</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill</td>
      <td>Gates</td>
      <td><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Xqko1Y9prZ6JoHkVERPfK6rJJuE=/0x0:640x427/1200x800/filters:focal(269x163:371x265)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56196289/billgatestock.0.jpg" width='100' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brian</td>
      <td>Bad Luck</td>
      <td><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-f4r5N2n5nz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LLysC2ZLPUo/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" width='100' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barista</td>
      <td>Hipster</td>
      <td><img src="http://diffuser.fm/files/2014/02/Hipster.jpg?w=600&h=0&zc=1&s=0&a=t&q=89" width='100' /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```